# How can I change my react app title on google search?

Tags: reactjs, seo

I deployed a website built using react. That site's is kbucard.com.
The problem is, if I search my web on google, like 'kbucard.com', then I can find it but my website's name is just "React App" and my website's description is "Web site created using create-react-app".

This image will help you understand my issue:

[image]

I already changed title tag and meta tags in index.html and I used react-helmet and also I installed babel-polyfill but nothing worked. I deployed this web on our university computer, used nginx and jenkins.

Please help me resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read "[Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618)" to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not). General SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The TL;DR answer is you need to wait for Google to crawl your site again and pick up the changes. There's no telling when that will be, but you should, at the bare minimum, go ahead and verify your site on [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about). it should help you diagnose future problems like this.

Comment: I really need an answer for this question

Comment: got the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927882/how-to-delete-created-using-create-react-app-from-links