# How can I change "created using create-react-app" in search results?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, create-react-app

I am trying to post the link to my portfolio onto linkedin and it always shows up with "Web site created using react app" as the description, which definitely doesn't make it look professional. It is deployed on my domain but is there any way I can get rid of all the create-react-app default stuff on my domain link?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

change the description and the title from your index.html file in the public folder then Rebuild your app

```
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
<meta
  name="description"
  content="Web site created using create-react-app"
/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

<title>React App</title>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the index.htm file in the public folder the title and meta tags will contain this default title.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add these meta tags into the header of your index.html
Also the image size should be minimum 1200x627 (as per the linkedin [documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687))

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="*TITLE*" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/linkedin.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="*DESCRIPTION*" />
</head>
```

If you're still having issues with LinkedIn recognising the new headers insert the url again but with a random parameter at the end of the url.

So if your site url is:
https://www.example.com

Try adding the link again with the empty parameter:
https://www.example.com?1

This should force linkedin to pull the new head data.