# Where is the text coming from in my site's search results listing?

Tags: html, reactjs

[image]

Why meta tags description and title are not displayed. More precisely, they are displayed, but not the ones you need.

The site is written in React. I am attaching the meta tag code of the index.html file

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />    
<meta name="description" content="Вернем 10% кешбека за первый заказ у нас. Новая фриланс биржа для заказчиков. Прозрачная оплата по частям, ваши деньги в безопасности! Заказывайте у нас любые проекты, а мы сделаем все, чтобы выполнить его максимально быстро!"     />
```

I changed all the meta tags as I needed, inserted my text there. But the site is still displayed that way.

Comment: Where did you put your meta tags? Did you look at the index.html file?

Comment: Do you use necessary `og` meta? And perhaps `<html lang="en">` ? Is *"en"* the desired? https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete "created using create-react-app" from links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63927882/how-to-delete-created-using-create-react-app-from-links)

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your help. I will check all your advice! I think everything will be fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Search Engines are your target, you seem to be in need of Open Graph meta tags or OG tags.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Finder" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Вернем 10% кешбека за первый заказ у нас. Новая фриланс биржа для заказчиков. Прозрачная оплата по частям, ваши деньги в безопасности! Заказывайте у нас любые проекты, а мы сделаем все, чтобы выполнить его максимально быстро!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="*insert image url*" />
```

You might also want to check Twitter Card tags for targetting Twitter. You might like this: https://ahrefs.com/blog/open-graph-meta-tags/